# LightGBM: Train metrics

Tags: lightgbm

I was trying to customise the training loss function for my LightGBM model. Could somebody help me with what loss function is used in the default setting, and where can I customize the same?

Answer (score 0):

> Could somebody help me with what loss function is used in the default setting

The default objective is `"regression"`, which is L2 loss.

> where can I customize the same?

You can see the other available built-in loss functions at https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#objective.

It is also possible to use a custom loss function that you write yourself, but the details for that depend on which programming language you are using.